# Ignoring someone can be considered aggressive?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology

On social networks I found many people who don't answer to some polite questions. In real life it would be considered unacceptable.

I've read an italian resource where it calls this way of behaving denying. Like I deny that you exist by not answering you.

I've read that it's also a manipulatory technique used by narcissists and borderline. Can you help me to make this statement more scientific?

This other question can lead to the answer: [Why being ignored is 'painful' for human beings?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/why-being-ignored-is-painful-for-human-beings)

It can be useful to check also [silent threatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_treatment)

Comment: Who downvoted could nicely explain the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To drop a relationship which has no direction (at this time in life) is healthy. Sometimes the reasons for which we drop a relationship reflect negatively on our personality and can result on hurt feelings for the person we are removing from our lives so it's best to do a clean cut for the other person and ourselves.

Technically this technique of quietly asserting ones self at the expense of someone else's feelings is called [passive aggressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior).

> an indirect negative behavior

Comment: I'm interested in this sentence: "Technically this technique of quietly asserting ones self at the expense of someone else's feelings is called passive aggressive. an indirect negative behavior" - can you better explain it?

Comment: In psychology In psychology, passive-aggressive behavior is characterized by a habitual pattern of passive resistance to expected work requirements, opposition, stubbornness, and negativistic attitudes in response to requirements for normal performance levels expected of others. Most frequently it occurs in the workplace where resistance is exhibited by such indirect behaviors as procrastination, forgetfulness, and purposeful inefficiency, especially in reaction to demands by authority figures, but it can also occur in interpersonal contexts.

Comment: So assertion is anytime we interact with another to change the situation to match our desires. We may actively interact with the group to express how we feel and what direction we think it should go. We we become upset we then express our feelings by saying the direction which is being taken upsets me and then work as a part of the society to resolve our feelings. Or we can passively work against the goal of the society by purposefully causing the plans to fail without actually acting aggressively or displaying any of the anger which remains inside.

Comment: thanks, you made me discover something very interesting. Really thanks! If I can suggest.. I would edit your answer to include the comments with the detailed explanations of passive aggressive. It will be more immediate useful and more upvoted I guess! but really thanks.