# Why being ignored is 'painful' for human beings?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology

Ignoring someone is a manipulatory technique used at times. Ignoring the attacks of someone else through emotional detachment has a very strong effect on the attacker.

Is there a name for this kind of manipulative behavior?

Comment: A lot of assumptions being made in this question without referring to any source, and a lot of tangential unfocused questions. Please focus on one. If you are after verification whether there is a concept/terminology for this behavior, start there. If there is, you can go from there to find documentation on it and ask your subsequent questions. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring is a type of social rejection see extracts from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_rejection):

> Social rejection occurs when an individual is deliberately excluded
> from a social relationship or social interaction. ... rejection can be either active, by bullying, teasing, or ridiculing, or passive, by ignoring a person, or giving the "silent treatment."
>
> ...
>
> Researchers have also investigated how the brain responds to social
> rejection. One study found that the dorsal anterior cingulate cortex
> is active when people are experiencing both physical pain and "social
> pain," in response to social rejection.